# .htaccess .php rewrite with / after

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

So I am currently rewritting my urls and removing the .php extension using the following:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

So if I load up the about.php page, http://example.com/about it displays what I want, is there a way to make http://example.com/about/ display the about.php page as well, as well as all the other files like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can drop the trailing slash if it exists, in your capture regex, like so:

```
RewriteRule ^([^\.|/]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

This will send requests for both `about` and `about/` to `about.php`.

Comment: This doesn't affect folders does it? I can still load javascript files in a subfolder and access subfolder urls if the php document doesn't exist?

Comment: To not affect files/folders that exist, use these two lines before the rewriterule: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d`

Comment: Awesome thank you, I really need to sit down and learn .htacess stuff. Maybe that will be my plan next weekend.